# How to ask a member of SO?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to ask a member with assumed better skills if I think that the member who is answering or commenting me doesn't understand me?

Comment: If they comment on your question and you reply to them with a comment they get a notification. If they don't reply then chances are they're simply not interrested. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: If someone leaves an answer that is incorrect, it will be downvoted by other experts. If someone leaves a comment that is wrong, it is very possible that an expert will leave a comment stating otherwise. I don't see how this is a real problem, and I certainly don't see why you think you have the right to bother other people without permission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No

Nor should there be and there is very little reason for it.  People generally do not want to be pestered.

You post a question and get a response in comment or as an answer - post a further comment politely asking for clarification or stating as such.

However, it is likely that the problem that causes the misunderstanding is in your question and thus should be made very clear.